# compress html signature from brackets with images

Tags: html, html-email, signature, adobe-brackets

Recently I designed a signature for a client. 
The client then asked me to html it to him. I saw some video tutorials and I did it fine. I have the html file and the images in a separate folder. 
    When I preview it with Brackets editor, it shows me the desired result. 
    When I open the HTML from my Windows Explorer, 
      the result is also the same as in Google Chrome.

**My main problem and question is:**
How will I be able to send the HTML to my client without sending the HTML file and the images together.

I want him to be able to click only one file and preview it in Chrome and copy the code in his mail. Is there a way to compress the HTML file and the images from my folder and create a file only that will have both?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Export the page with file > export as a PDF.

Comment: thks for your comment raymond,i did it and it when i open the pdf it shows me a code how do iuse it?i want to be able to send this to the client

Comment: convert your images to base64 and inline them

Comment: How about adding it as your signature? This way you will be able to see if it works and the client gets to see the signature.